# What is the best way to convert a 32bit float value to RGB for visualisation?

Tags: python, opencv, rgb

We have a camera that returns a depth map, which is pretty much just a 2d array of 32bit floats. We need to convert it to color, as grayscaling just wont do - 255 values is not enough. What is the best way to get RGB from such data?

Is there a way to auto-adjust color range so that the most diverse part of image gets the most colors? We are working in python so that would be preferred.

Also if there is a way to convert those using GPU to speed up the process that would be great!

Comment: Colours will add only few bits (if the image should be interpreted by humans, we need a chromatic scale). First you should normalize the image (know the max and min). The meaning of values, specific values, or what you should show is also extremely important for such task. Probably you need a functions which transform float in a range of int range (like gamma for colours), but this depends on the data (and noise level) e interpretation. So, there is no generic best way. I would consider some interactive "map" (like online maps: much information, on different levels)

Comment: Do you need the same distance to always be shown in the same colour so that you can directly compare two images? Or do you only ever look at a single image and you just want as many different distances to be distinguishable from each other without necessarily worrying which distance is which colour?

Comment: @Mark Setchell The second thing.

Comment: Have a look at CLAHE here... https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell This is pretty good, but I would still like to see a way to turn it into RGB spectrum, e.g.: float32 => (R255,G255,B255).